# Firefox multiple rowed textbox getting auotmatically filled in with some url like junk data

Tags: language-agnostic

We have an intranet php application developed for Firefox and it was running fine for almost 2 years. Now, for the last few days, the multiple-rowed textboxes are often getting filled in with some url like junk data. Sometimes, this happens only when you click on the textbox.

But when we ran the application in Google Chrome, we didn't face any problem. Is this anything to do with a firefox virus?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem didn't go even we reinstalled the Firefox browser. Finally, we reformatted the system. Firefox is now working okay.